# Защита роутов через middleware или что-то другое

Tags: php, laravel

Имею следующую схему данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `Users`. Таблица с данными пользователей
- `Journals`. Таблица со списком журналов.
- `Entries`. Таблица со списком записей в журналах.
- `journal_user`. Журнал могут вести разные пользователи. Таблица описывает права. Только те пользователи, которым указаны в этой таблице для определённого журнала, могут его вести.
- Связь от `Users` к `Entries`. Каждая запись в журнале принадлежит определённому пользователю.

Есть `Journal`, который могут заполнять `Entries` определённые `Users`. Каждая `Entry` принадлежит определённому `User`. И только пользователь, который сделал эту `Entry` может её редактировать. Имеется необходимость в следующих ограничениях:

- Для определённого `Journal` только определённые `Users` могут оставлять `Entries`. Остальные `Users` не должны иметь никаких прав на работу с `Journals` и `Entries`.
- Только тот `User`, который оставил `Entry` (при условии, что он всё ещё имеет права на работу с журналом, т.е. присутствует в таблице `journal_user`) может редактировать её. Остальные доверенные пользователи (из таблицы `journal_user` для текущего `Journal`) могут только читать.

Я не знаю, как подступиться к описанным выше требованиям к ограничениям. Самое удобное - сделать ограничение подобное на стороне middleware, который бы использовался в качестве middleware для группы роутов в web.php. И если с пользователем понятно (я могу получить его данные через Auth::user()), то как быть с Journal?

```
Route::get('journals/{journal}', 'JournalController@show')->name('journals.show');
```

Нужно проверить, что пользователь может открыть этот журнал. Значит на стороне middleware нужно как-то получить переданный параметр роута {journal}. Как это можно сделать?

Насчёт возможности редактирования только своей записи я вроде бы понимаю - реализовать можно через [Request и валидацию](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) (есть там метод auth). Но как быть с выше описанным? Это можно сделать как-то иначе? Да, я могу в каждом методе контроллеров проверять, но это же не правильно, да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как создать посредника маршрута в Laravel описано здесь [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware). Все действия сводятся к двум простым шагам - создание файла посредника и его последующая регистрация.  Назначим на маршрут наш посредник:

```
Route::get('journals/{journal}', 'JournalController@show')
  ->name('journals.show')
  ->middleware('journal.control');
```

Код посредника:

```
use App\Models\JournalUsers;

class JournalControl
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $journal = $request->route('journal');

    if($this->checkJournalRight($journal) {
      return $next($request);
    }

    return abort(404);
  }

  public function checkJournalRight($journal_id)
  {
    if(
      JournalUsers::where('user_id', session()->get('user_id'))
        ->where('journal_id', $journal_id)
        ->first()
    ) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Все легко и просто, в первом действии извлекаем параметр `journal` с маршрута, и ищем в таблице права пользователя на указанный журнал.

Теперь о записях в журнале(предполагаю что это отдельная сущность в виде таблицы, где есть ключ на `journal_id` и создателя `user_id`).

```
use App\Models\Entries;

public function checkRight()
{
  $right = Entries::where('user_id', session()->get('user_id'))
    ->where('journal_id', $request->route('journal'))
    ->where('id', $request->route('entry'))
    ->first();

  return (!empty($right)) ? true : false;
}
```

Использовать код в посреднике или контролере решать Вам. Код маршрута может выглядеть примерно так:

```
Route::get('journals/{journal}/entries/{entry}');
```

**PS.** Код написан на чистом энтузиазме. Я никогда не использовал стандартную регистрацию Laravel. Используйте свои данные вместо моих.

Comment: `JournalUsers` - зачем под каждую таблицу создавать модели?

Comment: @РустамГимранов Для удобства, пусть некоторые не так часто используются, но всё же они есть. Или Вы предлагаете использовать сырые выражения? Гораздо проще написать `new JournalUser()...->save()`, чем `DB::table()->insert.....`. Плюс у моделей много плюшек, и вдруг когда-то изменится название таблицы - нужно внести правки лишь в одном файле.

Comment: @РустамГимранов Польностью Вас поддерживаю в соглашениях фреймворка, но это всего лишь инструмент, а кто и как его использует - дело личное, ведь главное - чистый и понятный код.